# Ajax response value is always 1?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have java script in a html page that is sending to vars to a PHP script that then echos one var at the end. The response value is always 1, I have tried alerting, console.log and putting it in a box and nothing changes it.

My html/JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker.js"></script>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker2.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

 </head>
 <body>
     <input id="demo1" type="text" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
     <input id="demo2" type="text" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal2('demo2','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
     <button onclick="submit()">Click me</button>
     <div id=box></div>
     <script>
      function submit(){
       var div1 = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
       var div2 = document.getElementById("demo2").value;
       var ftest = new Date(div1);
       var ltest = new Date(div2);
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          else{
               xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

       xhttp.open("GET","calc.php?w1="+ftest+"&w2="+ltest,true);
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState==4)   
        {   
            alert(xhttp.responseText); 
        }   
       };
       xhttp.send(null);
      }
     </script>
 </body>   
</html>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php 
// function getWorkingDays($startDate,$endDate,$holidays) {
    $startdate = $_GET['w1'];
    $endDate = $_GET['w2'];
{crapton of math}

echo $workingDays;

?>
```

UPDATE: I changed the code so it was getting the value from the input instead of inner html but it is still return 1 no matter what.

Comment: `<input>` elements have no content, so `innerHTML` will return an empty string. `new Date("div1")` makes no sense. So, the reason why you always get the same response is because you are sending incorrect input.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML;
var div2 = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML;
var ftest = new Date("div1");
var ltest = new Date("div2");
```

Should be:

```
// Input fields have a value property
var div1 = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
var div2 = document.getElementById("demo2").value;
// Pass that value to date, not the string "div1/2"
var ftest = new Date(div1);
var ltest = new Date(div2);
```

That is, `div1` and `div2` should not have quotes around them (you are passing the constant values "div1" and "div2" instead of passing the variable values of vars `div1` and `div2`).

Comment: I changed my code to for this answer but I still get a return of one no matter what.